# Website doesn't open in Safari and iOS devices

Tags: nginx, ssl, ios

I have website unitbean.com
But something happend and it doesnt open on any browser on IOS devices.
Only IOS device. On other it i ok
I tried to change nginx configs, and etc, but the problem is the same.
What kind of problem it may be?
We use certbot for ssl

Answer (score 2):

Your site unitbean.com was served using a TLS certificate that doesn't contain that name. It only contains the names [www.oboi-ok.ru](http://www.oboi-ok.ru) and oboi-ok.ru. Replace the TLS certificate with one that contains the necessary names.